# Try and catch simple output error

Tags: javascript, html

Im new at this and I really dont know whats the problem with this code.. Please Help.. Tnx! This my whole .html file
PS: Even though I include the form tag, nothing happens

```
<input type="text" id="bitch" name="try1" required />
<button onClick="trycatch()">Click</button>
```

This is inside my script tag..

```
function trycatch() {
    var try1 = document.getElementById('bitch').value;
    try {
        if(try1 == "") {
            throw"empty1";
        }
        else if (isNaN(try1)) {
            throw"empty2";
        }
        else if((try1 > 100) || (try1 < 0)) {
            throw"invalid";
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        if(error == "empty1") {
            alert("Please enter a number!");
        }
        if(error == "empty2") {
            alert("Make sure it is a number!");
        }
        if(error == "invalid") {
            alert("Number range is 1-100!");
        }
    }

    if(try1 <= 99) {
        document.write("Your score is " try1);
    }
    else if(try1 == 100) {
        document.write("You got a perfect score!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the console (hit F12) to see if there are any errors?

Comment: Please provide more detail than "nothing happens".  And I don't see any `form` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `+` symbol here:

```
document.write("Your score is " + try1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your javascript syntax, this line is failing:

```
document.write("Your score is " try1);
```

Change it to:

```
document.write("Your score is " + try1);
```